# Can custom key-value pair be added to the firebase.auth().currentuser object?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, create-react-app

I have recently started using firebase for a create-react-app project and need to add a variable - pv to user object and update it regularly.. sort of like 'points'. Is it possible to do it? I could use firestore, but that's gonna be too much work for just one variable...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to add custom values to a Firebase Authentication user profile from the client-side SDKs.

If you want to store custom values for a user profile, the idiomatic way to do so is to store them in a database - using the UID of the user to identify the additional profile data for them.